# PHP: how do I create checkboxes from array?

Tags: php

On my wordpress site, I'd like to create checkboxes based on what is returned from the database. In the code I have so far (below) $enrolments is an object array. Each object contains firstname, surname etc.

```
$enrolments = get_user_enrolments();

foreach($enrolments as $enrolment)
?>
<p class="checkboxes form-row form-row-wide">
    <input type="checkbox" name="enrolments[]" value='$enrolment->firstname'>
</p>
<?php
```

Comment: What is the criteria for the checkbox being checked?  Having a value in `$enrolment->firstname`? Could you provide a `var_dump($enrolment);`

Comment: No, the checkboxes won't be created checked. They will be unchecked by default. The user checks them. The checkboxes need to have the label $enrolment->firstname.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood "create checkboxes based on what is returned from the database".  What you just asked for is as easy as `<label><input type="checkbox" name="enrolments[]" value='<?= $enrolment->id ?>' /><?= $enrolment->firstname ?></label>` (I presume you have a field named `id`)